# How to disable Spacebar and Tab keypress on a Web Page using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a "popup" div which when displayed I want to disable any `keypress` or `keydown` event on the page.

I tried this code below:

```
$(document).on('keypress keydown',function (e) {
var key = e.which;
if(key == 32 && $(".popup").is(":visible")){
  // console.log($(".popup").is(":visible"));
  // alert("keypresses yr "+(key == 32 && $(".popup").is(":visible")));
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
});
```

Here in `if` condition I check if key pressed is `spacebar (32)` and the `popup` box is visible than only disable `keypress`.

Did not work!

I am using jquery version `1.11.1`.

Comment: what is key inside if? use e.keyCode instead

Comment: @mayk: Tried that way also.. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your code to the following:

```
$(document).on('keypress keydown',function (e) {
    return $(".popup").is(":visible") && e.which !== 9 && e.which !== 32;
});
```

The code above will return every key pressed except **`tab`** and **`space`**, if the popup is visible.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(document).on('keypress keydown', function(e) {
  /* I changed it to ':focus' to demonstrate how it works inside the input */
  return $("#txt").is(":focus") && e.which !== 9 && e.which !== 32;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
```

Comment: Glad I could help you @HarshvardhanSolanki.